# What are PKCS#12 vulnerabilities?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I'm asking this under the assumption that every security protocol has a vulnerability.

Background: I'll be using PKCS#12 to send over a certificate and matching private key to iPads for them to install onto their device.  I will then have the user install the Cert/Priv key into their keychain and to use it as an identity when signing into other deployed machines.

Are there any common/critical mistakes done when implementing PKCS#12 ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue listed in the following documents. You may find some useful information.

http://www.drh-consultancy.demon.co.uk/pkcs12faq.html

ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/98workshop/privkey.pdf